# Show only sub menu after click on parent menu

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

This is my html code

```
<ul class="dd-options">
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option"><label class="dd-option-text">Main_parent1</label></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option">
        <label class="dd-option-text">- Main_child1</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option">
        <label class="dd-option-text">- Main_child2</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="minus">
        <a class="dd-option">
        <label class="dd-option-text">-- Sub_child1</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option">
        <label class="dd-option-text">Main_parent2</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option">
        <label class="dd-option-text">- Main_child3</label>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Output

```
Main_parent1
  - Main_child1
  - Main_child2
     -- Sub_child1
Main_parent2
  - Main_child3
```

First Time my output should be(already done)

```
Main_parent1
Main_parent2
```

If i have hover Main_parent menu it's open Main_child and Sub_child. But i want if hover Main_parent should open only Main_child only. if click Main_child
 should open Sub_child.

jQuery code

```
jQuery('.dd-options .dd-option-text').filter(function () {
    return jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text())[0] == '-';
}).closest('li').hide().addClass('minus');

jQuery('.dd-options > :not(.minus)').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).nextUntil(':not(.minus)').show();
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).nextUntil(':not(.minus)').hide();
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vikastyagi87/6URBK/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Its beacuse `Sub_child1` is an child of of the main `ul` element, you need to create a seperate `ul` for your sub menu:

```
<ul class="dd-options">
  <li>
    <a class="dd-option"><label class="dd-option-text">Main_parent1</label></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="dd-option">
    <label class="dd-option-text">- Main_child1</label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="dd-option">
    <label class="dd-option-text">- Main_child2</label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <ul>
    <li class="minus">
      <a class="dd-option">
      <label class="dd-option-text">-- Sub_child1</label>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <li>
    <a class="dd-option">
    <label class="dd-option-text">Main_parent2</label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="dd-option">
    <label class="dd-option-text">- Main_child3</label>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note the extra `ul` that contains the `Sub_child1` element

Answer (score -1):

```
you can handle this from css also

like 

parnet:hover ul(1) { display:block;} 
ul(1):hover ul{2}{ display:block;} 

HTML 

would be 

<ul>
   <li>first
        <ul>
               <li>fisrt sub child</li>
               <li></li>
        </ul>
   </li>


</ul>


no need to write jquery or javascript  like and u can google also css drop down menu
```